# Plot NetCDF multi-variable time series using Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to plot a time series from several 1-D variables residing in one NetCDF file. The NetCDF file output looks similar to below, with variables named differently than var[1..4].

```
dimensions:
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (12 currently)
variables:
        float var1(time) ;
        float var2(time) ;
        float var3(time) ;
        float var4(time) ;
        double time(time) ;
```

The following works when plotting one variable.

```
import netCDF4
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Data file
data = netCDF4.Dataset('./ts.nc', 'r')

# Print variables
par_list = data.variables.keys()
print par_list

# Read the variables
times = data.variables['time']
var1 = data.variables['var1']

# Convert times
t = netCDF4.num2date(times[:],times.units)

hs = pd.Series(var1[:],index=dtime)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
hs.plot(ax=ax,title='Test plot')
ax.set_ylabel(var1.units)
plt.savefig("test.png")
```

In addition to plotting multiple lines, I would like to format the lines. Variable 1 is related to Variable 2, and Variable 3 is related to Variable 4. So having the same line style and different colors for variables 1 and 2, and a different line style for variables 3 and 4 would be useful. Additionally, I am looking for a legend outside of the plot.